# Haskell "dependent" fields of a record?

Tags: haskell, record

I've got the following record defined:

```
data Option = Option {
    a    :: Maybe String,
    b    :: Either String Int
} deriving (Show)
```

Is there anyway for me to enforce that when a is `Nothing`, b must be a `Left` and when a is `Just`, b must be a `Right`? Maybe with phantom types, or something else? Or must I wrap the whole thing inside of an Either and make it `Either String (String, Int)` ?

Comment: I don't think Haskell 2010 has anything that allows this in your former solution. I would suggest going for `Either String (String, Int)`, or an isomorphic type such as `data Option = OptionA String | OptionB String Int`, where the constructors have sensible names.

Comment: To best answer this, it is important to know the *meaning* attached to `a` and `b`. Why is it that sometimes you don't have an `a` (e.g. it's `Nothing`)? Why is it OK to represent `b` as either a `String` *or* an `Int`? Why do you want to enforce the restriction you were talking about? This gives me the initial impression that `b` is not well defined.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should just use two constructors for the two possible shapes:

```
data Option = NoA String | WithA String Int
```

Of course, you should give them better names, based on what they represent. Phantom types are definitely overkill here, and I would suggest avoiding `Either` — `Left` and `Right` are not very self-documenting constructor names.

If it makes sense to interpret both Either branches of the b field as representing the same data, then you should define a function that reflects this interpretation:

```
b :: Option -> MeaningOfB
b (NoA s) = ...
b (WithA t n) = ...
```

If you have fields that stay the same no matter what the choice, you should make a new data type with all of them, and include it in both constructors. If you make each constructor a record, you can give the common field the same name in every constructor, so that you can extract it from any `Option` value without having to pattern-match on it.

Basically, think about what it *means* for the string not to be present: what does it change about the other fields, and what stays the same? Whatever changes should go in the respective constructors; whatever stays the same should be factored out into its own type. (This is a good design principle in general!)

If you come from an OOP background, you can think about this in terms of reasoning with composition instead of inheritance — but try not to take the analogy too far.